# is the complement graph of a connected complete bipartite graph is connected?

Tags: graph-theory

Is a complement graph of a connected complete bipartite graph connected? Here it clears the resulting graph is not bipartite. so what will be its answer? Am  I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement of a complete bipartite graph is never connected, since there is no connection between the two parts of the bipartite graph in the complement.